# computational algebra in $GF(2)[x]/p(x)$ using Fibonacci representation rather than Galois representation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm very familiar with the Galois representation of the quotient ring $GF(2)[x]/p(x)$ --- see [article on it that I wrote](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/1070.php) --- but was wondering if there is a straightforward method of computing in the Fibonacci representation instead.

In the Galois representation, $p(x)$ of degree $N$ is represented by a bit vector `p` of polynomial coefficients, so that for example $p(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1 \Longleftrightarrow$ `p = 100101`, and the following computational axioms apply:

- addition ⇔ bitwise XOR
- multiplication of $u$ by $x$ ⇔ shift `u` left by 1, and then XOR with `p` if it leads to a smaller binary number

In the Fibonacci representation:

- addition ⇔ bitwise XOR
- multiplication of $u$ by $x$ ⇔ `((u << 1) | parity(p & (u << 1))) & M`:  shift `u` left by 1, compute the parity of this masked with the polynomial bit vector `p`, then compute bitwise AND with $M=2^N-1$.

I can do this, but what I am not clear on is how to apply it to multiplication of two elements $u$ and $v$ of the quotient ring. With the Galois representation, it's easy; you basically loop over the bits of one element $u$ and multiply by successive powers of $x$ times the other element $v$, then add (XOR) in the partial results, just like ordinary binary multiplication but without carries.

With the Fibonacci representation, I don't think this is the case any more, because when decomposing the bits of one element, each position at bit $k$ does not represent $x^k$; for example, with `p = 100101`:

- $1 \Longleftrightarrow$ `000001`
- $x \Longleftrightarrow$ `000010`
- $x^2 \Longleftrightarrow$ `000101`
- $x^3 \Longleftrightarrow$ `001010`
- $x^4 \Longleftrightarrow$ `010101`
- $x^5 \Longleftrightarrow$ `101011`

(etc.)

Is there an efficient way to compute products in a Fibonacci representation, either directly with binary numbers, or making use of the product computed in a Galois representation?

My end goal is to compute $(x^k)u$ where $k$ is moderately large (1000-100000 range) and I want to avoid performing a loop that has to iterate $k$ times.

Comment: What is the "Fibonacci representation" of $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n x^n + (p(x))$ ? And why do you call "Galois representation" the fact to represent $a_n, n \in 0 \ldots N-1, a_n \in \mathbf{F}_q$ by a $N$ digit number in base $q$ ?

Comment: because there is correspondence between the bit representations and the state of a [linear feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) which has Galois and Fibonacci representations. $q=2$ is special and it does not generalize to other quotient rings.

Comment: The Fibonacci representation of some arbitrary element $u$ of the quotient ring is easy, you just follow the addition and multiplication by $x$ computational axioms in my description; you figure out bit representations of $1, x, x^2, \ldots x^{N-1}$ and if the corresponding $a_k$ is 1, you XOR in the bits corresponding to $x^k$ into the result. (This amounts to a conversion from Galois representation to Fibonacci representation. I'm not sure about the other direction of conversion, though.)

Comment: it is an acceptable definition because XOR is equivalent to addition mod 2. In my use of ⇔ the items on the left are formal mathematical elements and the items on the right are bitwise representations.

Comment: This isn't quite an acceptable definition. Forget about xor, it is addition $\bmod 2$. The question is how do you represent $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n x^n + (p(x)), a_n \in \mathbf{F}_2$. If the representation is linear then it suffices to define the representation of $x^n$.

Comment: hmmm... reversed polynomials seem to come into play between Fibonacci and Galois representations... I wish I could give you a formal definition (and I do agree that I haven't given you an acceptable *formal* definition), probably something to do with generating functions or trace computation, but it eludes me.

Comment: .. If your representation is $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n x^n+(p(x)), a_n \in \{0,1\} \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n F_n$ where $F_0 = 1,F_1 = 2, F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ then the first question is if you can find back $a_{N-1},a_{N-2},\ldots$ from it.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, but I could be wrong.